# Another beginner calculator, String to int

Tags: java

I'm also trying to build a calculator from scratch and searched a lot of similar topics on SO, but non of them seems te help my problem.

**The problem:**
When I press my result button I get

> 'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null'
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.Bob.Rekenmachine$isListener.actionPerformed(Rekenmachine.java:302)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

**My problem**
I'm not sure how I can display the result of my calculation. The conversion from String to INT seems to be failing

**My code:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Rekenmachine {
JButton deelknop;
JButton maalknop;
JButton minknop;
JButton plusknop;
JButton isknop;
JTextArea display;                              
JButton num1;
JButton num2;
JButton num3;
JButton num4;
JButton num5;
JButton num6;
JButton num7;
JButton num8;
JButton num9;
JButton nume1;
JButton num0;
JButton nume2;
String result1;
int result11;
int result22;
int uitkomst00;
String result2;
boolean deelknopkeus = false;
boolean plusknopkeus = false;
boolean minknopkeus = false;
boolean maalknopkeus = false;
String uitkomst;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rekenmachine r = new Rekenmachine();
    r.go();
}

public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rekenmachine");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    JPanel cijfers = new JPanel();
    buttons.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    buttons.setLayout(new BoxLayout (buttons, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    GridLayout cijferlayout = new GridLayout(4,3);
    GridLayout buttonslayout = new GridLayout(5,1);
    buttons.setLayout(buttonslayout);
    cijfers.setLayout(cijferlayout);
    cijfers.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    display = new JTextArea(1, 15);
    display.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    display.getCursor();                                                
    display.setToolTipText("Vul hier uw waarden is");
    display.setLineWrap(true);                                          
    display.setWrapStyleWord(false);






    JButton deelknop = new JButton("/");
    deelknop.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    deelknop.addActionListener(new deelListener());

    JButton maalknop = new JButton("*");
    maalknop.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    maalknop.addActionListener(new maalListener());

    JButton minknop = new JButton("-");
    minknop.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    minknop.addActionListener(new minListener());

    JButton plusknop = new JButton("+");
    plusknop.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    plusknop.addActionListener(new plusListener());

    JButton isknop = new JButton("=");
    plusknop.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    isknop.addActionListener(new isListener());

    JButton num1 = new JButton("1");
    num1.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));   
    num1.addActionListener(new num1Listener());


    JButton num2 = new JButton("2");
    num2.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num2.addActionListener(new num2Listener());

    JButton num3 = new JButton("3");
    num3.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num3.addActionListener(new num3Listener());

    JButton num4 = new JButton("4");
    num4.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num4.addActionListener(new num4Listener());

    JButton num5 = new JButton("5");        
    num5.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num5.addActionListener(new num5Listener());

    JButton num6 = new JButton("6");
    num6.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num6.addActionListener(new num6Listener());

    JButton num7 = new JButton("7");
    num7.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num7.addActionListener(new num7Listener());

    JButton num8 = new JButton("8");
    num8.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num8.addActionListener(new num8Listener());

    JButton num9 = new JButton("9");
    num9.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num9.addActionListener(new num9Listener());

    JButton nume1 = new JButton();
    nume1.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));

    JButton num0 = new JButton("0");
    num0.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));
    num0.addActionListener(new num0Listener());

    JButton nume2 = new JButton();
    nume2.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 30));


    cijfers.add(num1);
    cijfers.add(num2);
    cijfers.add(num3);
    cijfers.add(num4);
    cijfers.add(num5);
    cijfers.add(num6);
    cijfers.add(num7);
    cijfers.add(num8);
    cijfers.add(num9);
    cijfers.add(nume1);
    cijfers.add(num0);
    cijfers.add(nume2);


    mainPanel.add(display);
    buttons.add(deelknop);
    buttons.add(maalknop);
    buttons.add(minknop);
    buttons.add(plusknop);
    buttons.add(isknop);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cijfers);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, mainPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, buttons);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);





} class num1Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "1");
            result1 = display.getText();                             


}
}
class num2Listener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result1 = display.getText(); 
        display.setText(result1 + "2");
        result1= display.getText();                             




 }
   }
    class num3Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "3");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num4Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "4");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num5Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "5");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num6Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "6");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num7Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "7");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num8Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "8");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num9Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "9");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class num0Listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            display.setText(result1 + "0");
            result1= display.getText();                             


}
}
    class plusListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            result1 = display.getText(); 
            plusknopkeus = true;
            display.setText("");

    }   
    }
class maalListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        maalknopkeus = true;
        display.setText("");                
    }   
    }

class deelListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        deelknopkeus = true;
        display.setText("");                
    }   
    }

class minListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        minknopkeus = true;
        display.setText("");                
    }   
    }
class isListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        result2 = display.getText();

        if ( plusknopkeus == true ) 
        result11 = Integer.parseInt(result1);
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        uitkomst00 = Integer.parseInt(uitkomst);
        uitkomst00 = result22 + result11;



        display.setText(uitkomst00);

    }
}
```

**My code line 293-303:**

```
    class isListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        result2 = display.getText();

        if ( plusknopkeus == true ) 
        result11 = Integer.parseInt(result1);
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        uitkomst00 = Integer.parseInt(uitkomst);
        uitkomst00 = result22 + result11;
```

**Extra info**

I know my code can be a lot smaller, working with loops etc. I'm just figuring out how I can make my calculator work and then I will tidy thing up. I hope the code is readable for you though.

Comment: Another beginner who didn't hear about debug

Comment: Learn to debug your code it will help you in long term you cannot survive programming job without debugging skills. By the way Numberformatexception means you're not passing number while conversion

Comment: Thank you for the debugging tips. I tried to figure it out (working in eclipse) but I couldn't find where it goes wrong. I know, my debugging skills are very low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed your event handlers and created a extra method `resetOprations()`

```
class plusListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result2 = display.getText();
        resetOprations();
        plusknopkeus = true;
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        display.setText("");

    }
}

class maalListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result2 = display.getText();
        resetOprations();
        maalknopkeus = true;
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        display.setText("");
    }
}

class deelListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result2 = display.getText();
        resetOprations();
        deelknopkeus = true;
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        display.setText("");
    }
}

class minListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        result2 = display.getText();
        resetOprations();
        minknopkeus = true;
        result22 = Integer.parseInt(result2);
        display.setText("");
    }
}

public void resetOprations() {
    deelknopkeus = false;
    plusknopkeus = false;
    minknopkeus = false;
    maalknopkeus = false;
}

class isListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // result2 = display.getText();
        result11 = Integer.parseInt(result1);

        display.setText(result22 + "");
        if (plusknopkeus) {
            result22 = result22 + result11;
        } else if (minknopkeus) {
            result22 = result22 - result11;
        } else if (maalknopkeus) {
            result22 = result22 * result11;
        }else if (deelknopkeus) {
            result22 = result22 / result11;
        }
        display.setText(result22 + "");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this contribution! I implemented the code and it's working perfectly! Now I can go on and focus on making the code better!